# How would i get get min Y value for graph?

Tags: javascript, graph

I don't know how to explain this but i will try my best, so sorry in advance

For example this numbers 
i would like to get

> 5 => 1,   12 => 10,   128 => 120,   1493 => 1400,   13301 => 13000

I have came up with `Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(x)));`

which returns me 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the exponent and a factor and check if the value is smaller than 100, then take just the decimal with the exponent or the adjusted value.

```js
function format(v) {
    var e = Math.floor(Math.log10(v)),
        f = 10 ** (e - 1);
    return v < 100
        ? 10 ** e
        : Math.floor(v / f) * f;
}

console.log(...[5, 12, 128, 1493, 13301, 239584].map(format));
//              1, 10, 120, 1400, 13000, 230000
```